# Is Aerial View officially gone from maps in Microsoft's Bing?

Tags: bing-maps

I see Bird's Eye view is still available, but the Aerial View was much more valuable for spotting landmarks, evaluating real estate, neighborhoods, etc.  Plus it was just a whole lot more interesting.

I spent some time searching, but found no comments from anyone about the missing fly-over aerial pictures.  Anyone know if they are just going through a transition or are they gone for good?

Comment: Ok, I see my question is about a web service and thus a purist will flag to close it; however, I'm seeking an answer regardless.  Since superuser is for hardware and software related questions and not website software, err service, related questions; is there a stackexchange site for webservice related questions?

Comment: The votes to close are actually for migration. Your question is on its way, after a couple more votes, to webapps.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Have people forgotten what spam looks like? There was an answer on this crying for some flags.

Answer (score 2):

Looks as if it has been removed officially.. Check out this [article](http://news.cnet.com/8301-27076_3-20021530-248.html) from CNET. Along with that is [this](http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2010/11/02/changes-to-bird-s-eye-and-3d-maps.aspx) blog from Bing's Blog.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the [blog](http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2010/11/02/changes-to-bird-s-eye-and-3d-maps.aspx) they are **not** doing away with the feature.

I seem to recall map view menu having the following items:

**Satellite** - old fuzzy satellite images
**Bird's Eye** - new, closer, higher resolution satellite images
**Aerial** - beautiful images taken by airplane.  Not all areas included Aerial and some only included a single pass by the plane so rotation wasn't always available.

If my memory is correct and I'm understanding the blog, then what they are doing is eliminating the "Aerial" term, but enhancing the "Bird's Eye" view feature with the aerial images.  So, I have some hope that they'll restore the images of my area soon.

Answer (score 0):

They have **not** done away with the feature.  They have eliminated the term "Aerial View" from the menu, which will eventually lead to a simpler interface and less confusion.  However, to add to confusion for now, there is also a slight glitch in their interface.  If set to bird's eye view, you will see a high-res, modern satellite view and if you zoom into these images eventually you'll see the traditional broken image graphics that indicate you cannot zoom any further for detail; however, if you zoom again, you might see the original aerial view as taken by aircraft instead of satellite.